# Python brute forcing zip files

Tags: python, encryption, zip

Ive been working on a program in Python, which cracks encrypted zip files. The problem is, part of my programs key functions doesn't work.

How my program's meant to work...

> User enters in zip file name.
>
> User enters min password length.
>
> User enters max password length.
>
> Program will enter a loop, where it will gen a password that is within the min & max numbers.
>
> Program will try to open the zip with the password.
>
> Program will then print out the password if it was successful or not.

It is the 2nd last step that my program messes up on.

Instead of stooping when the passwords match, the program continues, and then tries another password. I think this is happening because there is an error happening when it tries to open the zip. So even if the password's match, its just going straight to the "except:" statement.

Here is my code which messes up -

```
# Function which tries to open zip (The buggy function)
def extract(zip_name, password, number):
    print("\nAttempt", number)
    # Tries and opens the zip
    try:
        zip_name.extractall(pwd=password)
        print("Success: " + password)
        exit(0)
    except:
        print("Failed: " + password)
```

Can anyone please show me how to make this work. Thanks

Comment: [to, two and too](http://www.bristol.ac.uk/arts/exercises/grammar/grammar_tutorial/page_15.htm) are not interchangeable.

Comment: Could you cut the code down to a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problematic step, and expand on *"messes up"*?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I edited it down to just the important info, and I added some more detail on whats going wrong

Comment: Why don't you print the exception if you think that's the cause. Swallowing and continuing is rarely the best choice...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens when you call `exit(0)`? Well, if you read the documentation for the [`exit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#exit) built-in, then you'll see that it says:

> when called, raises `SystemExit` with the specified exit code

so it raises an exception, but in your program this is inside a `try: ... except: ...` so the next thing that happens is that the exception is caught and the program prints `Failed` and continues.

This is why people often give the advice "[don't use a bare `except:`](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/doanddont.html#except)" — you almost never want to catch `SystemExit`.

Instead you could catch the actual exception raised by `zipfile` when the password doesn't match, which seems to be `RuntimeError`. Additionally, it would improve the program if you replaced the `exit(0)` with something like `return True`, and handle success or failure at a higher level of your program.